# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and vat

Tags: python, django, math, models

I seem to be having a problem multiplying in Django. I want to multiply the Total Purchase including VAT with my VAT value. Unfortunately, I got this error.

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and 'VAT'
```

It looks like my program calls `vat` (see views) `'VAT' rather than decimal. I'm not sure why there is an error unless there is another way around it.

**Views.py**

```
purchases = Purchase.objects.all()
vat = purchases[0].vat
total_purchases = Purchase.objects.all().aggregate(price = Sum('amount'))
total_purchases_vat = total_purchases['price'] * vat
```

**models.py**

```
class VAT(models.Model):
    vat = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 4, decimal_places = 1)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.vat)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    vat_period = models.ForeignKey(VAT_Period)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    description =  models.TextField(max_length = 400)
    vat = models.ForeignKey(VAT)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.amount)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`purchases[0].vat` yields an instance of the `VAT` model. You need to use `purchases[0].vat.vat` to get the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, did you mean to say:

```
vat = purchases[0].vat.vat
```